# Find Gene name in Column A and put the given ID in column B

Tags: excel

I have an excel Sheet with 2 columns, in this form

```
ADRBK2  NA
ADRBK2  NA
A1CF    ID1
A2M     ID2
ADRBK2  NA
```

Now what I want to achieve is that i look up the gene ADRBK2 in Column A and where ever i find this gene in Column A in my file, I want to put ID3 at the column B next to it. How can i Achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your data alphabetically, put ID3 in cell next to first ADRBK2, drag by left bottom corner of the ADRBK2 cell to the end of empty cells(simple copy).